# Font awesome 5 svg icon and text align vertically on the top

Tags: html, css, font-awesome-5

I have an example on codepen, [`code source`](https://codepen.io/ZokiPokiDev/pen/gQbNoO) and like icon and text to be aligned vertically. Is there a nice way to do this without JS code? I like to keep line-height from li element and other styles.

Comment: Do you want to preserve the current HTML structure?

Comment: The html structure if is needed can be changed but I don't like to touch the structure in inside the li element

Comment: What do you mean vertically aligned? If you mean that the text should be in the middle if the icon, then, they're already aligned. The problem is that the icon is not symmetrical, and it creates an illusion that they're not aligned.

Comment: I like the icon and the text to be in the line, on the top,

Answer (score 1):

Add vertical-align: middle to the svg element:

```
.svg-inline--fa.fa-li {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Remove position: abosolute from the existing .fa-li css class as this is breaking the layout and preventing vertical-align: middle to work properly

```
.fa-li {
    /*left: -2em; */
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 2em;
    line-height: 1.6;
}
```

Comment: `line-height` is not working on the **icon** and `vertical-align: middle;` don't change icon behavior. The other style in the fa-li el is already there by default from fa awesome

Answer (score 0):

Can't you put padding-top to the fa icon to align it with the text? Something like

```css
.fa-amazon {
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Yes this is ok, but 5px is fixed and I need some solution that this number won't be a fixed, I like this number to depend on the line-height and font-size, to calc somehow dynamically